# Combinatory of 10 indistinguishable turists in 4 completely different ships

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find how can $10$ indistinguishable tourists be sorted in $4$ different ships with the following conditions.

1. No conditions
2. Minimum $1$ tourist in each boat
3. Minimum $1$ and maximum $3$ tourist in each boat
4. Minimum $1$ and maximum $3$ tourist in each boat, knowing there are $2$ kids among the tourists that need to go with an adult(I suppose it means no $1$ kid alone in a boat or $2$ kids alone in a boat)

The problem is that I don't have the solutions for this problem.

For the first question I got $\frac{13\times12\times11}{3\times2\times1}$ and for the second question $4^6$.

I don't know if these results are correct nor how to solve $3$ and $4$.
Maybe inclusion-exclusion in $3$?
This is a problem from an exam.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to MSE. can you please provide your workings. Specifically where you got stuck, and what you need help with?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the solutions for this problem. For the first question I got 13·12·11/ 3·2·1 and for the second question 4^6. I don't know if these results are correct nor how to solve 3 and 4. Maybe inclusion-exclusion in 3?

Comment: Please add these comments to the original question. It would be useful to also indicate (in the question rather than as comments) in case the problem is from some particular book or is a HW problem for the benefit of other users of MSE.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance and my bad english

Comment: Your answers are incorrect.  Since the tourists are indistinguishable, the first problem is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.  The second problem can be reduced to a combination with repetition problem by first placing a tourist in each boat.

Comment: The tourists are indistinguishable because they are wearing COVID masks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, we would have $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{13}{3}$ ways of distributing the tourists.

**Explanation:**
This is an instance of the "stars and bars" problem. See [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/identical-objects-into-distinct-bins/) for details.

For the second problem, the answer would be $\binom{9}{3}$ as you want to choose places for 3 separators from amongst 9 spaces between the tourists. Details also [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/identical-objects-into-distinct-bins/).

---

For the third problem, for the fully general case, you want to cast it as a recursion. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1320053/439353) for details. Since we are working with a small enough problem, we can break it into cases.

Case 1: Observe that if any 1 boat has 1 passenger, then the other three are restricted to have 3 passengers each. Since the boats are distinct, we choose the boat with 1 passenger in 4 ways.

Case 2: If a boat has a minimum of 2 and maximum of 3 passengers, then the only allocations are $\{2,2,3,3\}$ amongst the 4 ships. We can choose the 2 ships with 2 passengers in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

Thus the total number of allocations for the third problem is 4+6 = 10

---

For the fourth problem, we have to presume the kids are distinguishable from tourists? This is not very clear to me, and therefore I'm not sure. Please check in case the below makes sense:

**Possible Approach:** First divide 8 indistinguishable adult tourists amongst 4 ships with minimum of 1 and max of 3. Then allocate the kids separately keeping in mind constraint of maximum of 3.

**Calculations:** The ways of accocating 8 adults amongst 4 ships are $\left\{\{1,1,3,3\},\{1,2,2,3\},\{2,2,2,2\}\right\}$. We will consider these as cases

Case 1 - $\{1,1,3,3\}$: We will choose 2 boats to contain the 1 passenger each in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways. We can then allocate 2 kids to the first boat or second boat containing 1 passenger, or allocate them 1 each to the two boats - a  total of 3 allocations. Thus the total number of ways is $6\times 3=18$

Case 2 - $\{1,2,2,3\}$: We will choose 2 boats to contain the 1 passenger in $\binom{4}{1}=4$ ways, and of the remaining boats, the one containing 3 passengers (of the 3 remaining ships) in $\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways. Therefore total number of ways of choosing adults in ships is $12$. We can then allocate (1) both kinds to the boat containing 1 passenger, (2) 1 to the boat containing 1 passenger and 1 to one of the boats with 2 passengers in 2 ways (3) allocate one kid each to the boat with 2 passengers. This is a total of 4 ways. Thus the total number of allocations is $12\times 4=48$

Case 3 - $\{2,2,2,2\}$: All boats contain only 2 passengers. We will choose the two boats to allocate 2 kids in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

Therefore the total number of allocations in all these cases is $18+48+6=72$ allocations for this question.